# Execute shell script directly, without .sh file

Tags: shell

Should it be possible to just write something like

```
for i in 1 2 do echo $i done
```

in the command line and have it run? Because when I try to do this, nothing happens but > being printed each time I press enter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in 1 2; do echo $i; done
```

The `;` symbolizes separation of commands. It would be the same as this:

```
$ for i in 1 2
> do
> echo $i
> done
1
2
$
```